# Eevee Volumetric Scatter Stepping/Banding

Tags: eevee-render-engine, volumetrics

I'm trying to make a scene for rendering a comet in Blender, as seen by spacecraft camera (i.e. realistically). The comet is done using voluminetrics, with density (and as such, reflectivity) falling off with inverse square of distance.

Problem is, after certain distance I run into severe stepping issues. Anyone knows how to fix it or if there's a workaround?

[image: test render]

Comment: Have you tried reducing the tile size in volumetric settings?

Comment: Yes, it's already at 2px. The sample # is at 256 and depth is adjusted using Python to place the samples where they matter, i.e. where the nucleus is visible. The bands also stay in place as I move camera back and front so they're not sampling related, they're linked with volumetric density.